# Bash script to check a row in an SQL file

Tags: bash

I need create a script bash to check if a line containing the string "Dump success" exists in different files SQL in several repository.

SQL files are placed in the followed tree structure : /tmp/backup/nameofserver/nameofdb/file_yyyymmdd_hhmm.sql

We must check on the most recent sql file

I don't know how to go about it

Thx

Comment: You wrote in your question: _in several repository_ Do you mean several, different directories? If yes, then how do you know which directories to search?

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` to search for a string in a file

Use `ls -t  | head -n1` to get the last modified file in the directory

Putting it together:

`grep "Dump success" $(ls -t | head -n1)`

Comment: This will perform the grep on the file names and not the contents.

Comment: @RamanSailopal you are correct. I have updated my answer. Now it should search in the latest file

Answer (score 0):

Use find to find all sql files in parent and child directories. Print the modification date in epoch format as well as "-" and the directory name and "- " and the file name. Use awk to get the epoch date, directory and filename using directory and epoch as indexes of a 2 dimensional map array, with the filename as the value. Loop through the array at the end and set the last file name (fil) for each directory, using this to form a grep command that is executed with the system function. The execution will print each file path for sql files that have the text "Dump successful" within.

```
find /tmp/backup -name "*.sql" -printf "%Ts - %h - %f\n" | awk '{ map[$3][$1]=$5 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for (i in map) { for (j in map[i]) { fil=map[i][j] } system("grep -l \"a\" "i"/"fil) } }'
```

Comment: Thx
But I don't really know the bash syntax.

I think we need :
For each server folder
go in
for each db folder
go in
select the most recent .sql file
check if it ends well with "Dump success"
If yes: ok
If not: problem

Comment: What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Check the latest amendments.